# IntelliJ - How to set the default jar file name in artifact

Tags: intellij-idea

Each one of my modules has same version in their pom files:

```
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

I would like for my artifact to strip the version part when exploding folders to Tomcat application.

[image: IntelliJ]

I know I can rename them manually:

[image: IntelliJ rename]

But I have to do this every time I deploy my application.

Does anyone know if there is a way around this, so I keep the jar names in artifact by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the name of your JAR file by configuration of the Maven Jar Plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>YourName</finalName>                   
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

For more details, [have a look at the docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#finalName).

Comment: I already did that in each of my module's pom files but this has nothing to do with the artifact I am building and dumping jars inside of it. It always defaults to jar with version